# Keras LSTM Converges on the Dataset's Mean Value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Snippet of data:

> [ 1.,   0.52916667  0.55, 0.5375      0.55714286  0.54285714   0.09395973]
>
> [ 0.,   0.59285714  0.55, 0.5,  0.53076923  0.5,   0.09395973]
>
> [ 0.,   0.53076923  0.5375      0.,   0.5375      0.5,   0.08277405]
>
> [ 0.,   0.55625     0.55833333  1.,   0.53888889  0.52777778   0.08137584]
>
> [ 1.,   0.52222222  0.52857143  0.54, 0.55, 0.55,  0.10834132]
>
> [ 1.,   0.6875      0.6125      0.575       0.53, 0.52,  0.09395973]
>
> [ 0.,   0.55666667  0.55, 0.55833333  0.52647059  0.52058824   0.08137584]
>
> [ 0.,   0.53529412  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,   0.02205177]
>
> [ 0.,   0.52083333  1.,   1.,   0.54, 0.58,  0.34563758]
>
> [ 0.,   0.55, 0.6,  0.5,  0.58, 0.5,   0.09395973]
>
> [ 0.,   0.67, 0.5,  0.,   0.5,  0.5,   0.07957814]
>
> [ 0.,   0.51764706  1.,   1.,   0.54166667  0.55,  0.16107383]

Each row in this timeseries dataframe contains 7 features and I'm trying to predict whether the first feature of the next time step will be a 1 or a 0.

To achieve this I have shifted everything forward one time step to create the labels, like so:

```
def windows(data):
    x_window_size = 100
    y_window_size = 1
    dataX, dataY = [], []

    for i in range(len(data)-x_window_size-y_window_size):
        x_window_data = data[i:(i+x_window_size)]
        y_window_data = [data[(i + x_window_size + y_window_size)]]
        dataX.append(x_window_data)
        y = [x[0] for x in y_window_data]
        dataY.append(y)

    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)
```

The model:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(100, 7))

x = CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = CuDNNLSTM(128)(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

optimiser = keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(
    loss="mse",
    optimizer=optimiser
    )
```

If I run 10,000 rows of data through the model, after 10 epochs I get the following:

[image]

Looks okay... but my dataset is actually 4 million rows. When I ran the full 4 million rows through training it just predicts the mean of the Y values (0.5):

[image]

The results are the same after 1 or 10 epochs. I can't figure out what's going on here. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Well I'm trying to predict the probability that the following time step will be a 1 or a 0 so I'm expecting the predictions to be values between 1 and 0 with a large amount of variation. So predictions such as 0.4, 0.2, 0.7 etc. are to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are many different ways, why this could be.

1. In the past I had similar problems, where the output was also just the average. I worked there with stock price prediction. For Machine Learning algorithm it is just very difficult to extract meaningful information from stock information, that is why it starts predicting either random results or just the average like in your case. And this is probably the best a model can get (in predicting stock prices),because the stock prices go up and down random as well. Unfortunately, in this case there is not much you can do.
2. Second scenario is that you have too little data. Although you have 4 million rows of data, this sometimes is not enough to generalize a problem and you still need to get more data.
3. This is the most likely scenario. Your model architecture is wrong. Your true data is either 0 or 1, therefore it should be a classification problem. Change your model architecture to something like this:

You still need to do the fine tuning, I have not tested this.

```
x = CuDNNLSTM(128)(inputs)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid')(x)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Additional your model probably has still too much noise in it. You can try a model with layers 64-64-1 instead of your model 128-128-128 or even try 32-1. And you can adjust the Dropout layer as well to like 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 or even more. If your model has to much noise, then it is just try and error, trying to get the noise out.

Recourses:

[Machine Learning Mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/binary-classification-tutorial-with-the-keras-deep-learning-library/)

[Binary Classification](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)